# How to handle incorrect edits by Community♦?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

In the [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832373/203657) code was changed from `mouseReleased` to `mousePressed`.

Several points here:

- it is an invalid edit because it's a hefty change of the answer. So it shouldn't have happened in the first place, as a suggested edit it would have been rejected
- normally, I would rollback the edit and leave a comment. Did the latter, but can't rollback, because it was cut in stone by a diamond.
- could edit the question again, make the edit a code-comment and re-add the old version, might start an edit battle..

So my question is: what's the preferred thingy to do?

Comment: Who says it is cut in stone? The rollback link works just fine.

Comment: A suggested edit by the Community user is a suggested edit by an anonymous user... It **would** have gone through the normal suggested edit review queue, and was infact accepted by 3 users (http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/773000)

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmm ... don't see a rollback link

Comment: @kleopatra: on the *previous* revision; click it to roll back to that previous revision. You cannot revert back to the current revision so there never is a rollback link on that one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters outch ... silly me - thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was an edit [suggested by an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2377870) which was approved by three reviewers. And Community user own anonymous user's suggested edits. But if you think it is an invalid edit, just rollback it. No one will stop you if you are correct.

Also you can't ask the edit reason to suggester as it is an anonymous. But you may ask to the reviewers who approved it.